# Anyone know of a tool to convert SSRS (RDL) reports to Crystal Reports (RPT)?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, reporting-services

I'm looking for a tool that will assist in the conversion from SSRS to Crystal. I've found numerous tools that will go the other way (From Crystal to SSRS), but none that will work for my specific need.

Comment: Can you import the SQL Server tables into Crystal and use them to build your Crystal version of your report?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no converters that go from SSRS to Crystal.